# How to do a specific gap in PYGAME boundaries in top?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision, boundaries

So basically I am trying to remove a gap from the top boundaries (see photo below), but how do I do it? I want to leave this very specific gap.

[image]

This is my code for boundaries:

```py
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
BOUNDRY_LEFT = 25
BOUNDRY_TOP = 25
BOUNDRY_RIGHT = SCREEN_WIDTH - 25
BOUNDRY_BOTTOM = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 25
```

And boundaries collision:

```py
if player_rect.left < BOUNDRY_LEFT:
    player_rect.left = BOUNDRY_LEFT
if player_rect.right > BOUNDRY_RIGHT:
    player_rect.right = BOUNDRY_RIGHT 
if player_rect.top < BOUNDRY_TOP:
    player_rect.top = BOUNDRY_TOP 
if player_rect.bottom > BOUNDRY_BOTTOM:
    player_rect.bottom = BOUNDRY_BOTTOM
```

Comment: You'll have to expand the conditions. `if player_rect.top < BOUNDRY_TOP:` is too broad.

Comment: I know that it is too broad, but I just cant get how exactly to take a bite out of that top boundry

Comment: Something like `if player_rect.top < BOUNDRY_TOP and player_rect.left < SCREEN_WIDTH - 200:`. It's up to you to define the exact x-coordinate where you don't want to check for the top position.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can simplify the boundary checking using [`pygame.Rect.contains`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains):

> test if one rectangle is inside another. Returns true when the argument is completely inside the Rect.

and [`pygame.Rect.clamp`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp):

> moves the rectangle inside another

```py
area_rect = pygame.Rect(BOUNDRY_LEFT, BOUNDRY_TOP, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
if not area_rect.contains(player_rect):
    player_rect = player_rect.clamp(screen_rect)
```

The gap above is only an exception (logical `and`) to the condition. Create a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) object for the gap and use [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to test if the player collides with the gap:

```py
area_rect = pygame.Rect(BOUNDRY_LEFT, BOUNDRY_TOP, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
gap_rect = pygame.Rect(SCREEN_WIDTH-200, 0, 200, BOUNDRY_TOP) 

if not area_rect.contains(player_rect) and not gap_rect.colliderect(player_rect):

    player_rect = player_rect.clamp(screen_rect)
```